# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Dual Boot Install with Windows 11 fails

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I am trying to install a dual boot windows linux system.
I have a fresh install of windows 11 on a 300GB partition and then I run the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS install after that on another 180GB partition. The Ubuntu installer offers to do a parallel install to windows with option to choose at boot which OS I want to run, but this sadly just doesn't happen. The install works but after that Windows starts automatically. I can start the linux OS from a USB stick but I don't know what to do from there, I tried some grub-install commands based on some posts from years ago but none of that seems to work anymore.
I also tried the install several times over, no luck.
Hardware is a new HP 255 G9 laptop with 16GB RAM and 512GB SSD, CPU AMD Ryzen 5 5625U.
How can I fix this?
Many thanks for any ideas people! :-)

Comment: You could try a newer version of Ubuntu because CPU processor may need a newer Linux kernel with newer hardware drivers and the Windows system may need a rather new and strict boot procedure in UEFI mode with secure boot and TPM on. You can download an **Ubuntu 23.10 iso file**, flash it to the USB stick and maybe it cna make a working installed system. Otherwise, maybe turn off some of the 'locks', for example secure boot and try to install and/or run the installed system again.

Comment: HP seems to be the only vendor that does not support UEFI boot order changes with efibootmgr. Grub and users use efibootmgr `man efibootmgr` to change boot order and other UEFI settings. With HP most have reported that they can go into UEFI settings, not the UEFI boot menu and change boot order there. Note that Windows updates or UEFI updates may reset Windows as first in boot order.

Comment: Thanks guys that is interesting.

Comment: I now discovered I can actually boot the Ubuntu partition from the hard disk but it isn't very comfortable.
First press esc during boot - brings up "Startup Menu". From that select "F9 Boot Menu". that gives another menu "Please select boot device" with choices for UEFI boot manager windows or linux
I guess I don't quite understand what menus and what partition belong to what OS or how things jump from one to the other.
So it sort of works just a lot more menus and keypresses necessary to start ubuntu.
When I last played with this stuff it was just grub, MBR, partitions, no UEFI or TPM.

Comment: I'm glad you found a working method, even if it is somewhat inconvenient. It seems to me that the computer *can* boot Ubuntu with the current settings, but for some reason cannot boot via grub. It should be possible to repair/reinstall grub and get the more convenient start procedure that you had when you last played with it.